# Postgres query giving syntax error at or near "where"

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a postgres query to fetch data from table "like"

Code is

```
$query = 'select * from like  where (discovery=? and user=?);';
$res = pg_query_params($query, array($_POST['discovery_id'], $_POST['user_id']));
```

However this on execution give error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 1: select * from like  where (discovery=? and user=?);
                        ^ in
```

How can I execute this query properly?
i have another tables named discovery and user. could that be the issue?

Comment: like is a keyword in [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html). Have you tried 'select * from ` like `  where (discovery=? and user=?);';

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You mean double quotes. But not sure how escape double quoute on that string

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yeah, I originally wrote "double quotes", than for some reason changed to backticks. I deleted the comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner You close it using a Mysql answer instead of Postgresql. In Mysql you use backticks, on postgresql you use double quoutes

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You're right; thought it covered it. Reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$query = 'select * from "like" where (discovery=? and user=?);';
```

Comment: its again showing <b>Warning</b>:  pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near &quot;\&quot;
LINE 1: select * from \&quot;like\&quot; where (discovery=? and user=?);
                      ^ in

Comment: Show us your create table for `"like"`? Postgresql is case sensitive. and echo your $query  to make sure show `"like"`

Comment: i have another tables named discovery and user. could that be the issue?

Comment: Nope that shouldn't be a problem because those are treated as fields. But for testing you can remove the `WHERE` part and the parameters. Again the problem is the back quotes so echo the `$query` variable to make sure you escape the character correctly.Also  TRY `select * from "like"` direct on postgresql.

Comment: of course you should avoid using reserved keywords as table names.

Comment: You dont have to escape the quote (`\"`) unless you start the string with `"` so just `.. select * from "like" ..` is fine, because well.. literal string.

Comment: @Xorifelse are you sure? because the line is `$query = 'select * from like ...`

Comment: @Xorifelse nevermind. You are right I swear i read was `$query = "select * from like ..."`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza now the error changed to pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer =?
LINE 1: select * from &quot;like&quot; where (discovery=? and user=?);
                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. in

Comment: again show us the `CREATE TABLE`. but here look like your parameter are wrong. Are those integer or strings? First try `$query = 'select * from like  where (discovery=123 and user=\'somestring\');';`   strings in postgresql use single quotes so you have to escape it.

Comment: got it fixed as $query = 'select * from "like" where (discovery=$1 and user=$2);'; thanks

Comment: No problem, remember accept the answer so people know the issue is solved.